# input autofill problem with default background color and focus not triggering autofill popup

Tags: css, vue.js, input, vuejs3, tailwind-css

Im using tailwind css and vue, I have two problems with input type email.
input setup: type=email, name=email, autocomplete=on

1st problem: for example chrome has default autofill color light blue and I cannot get rid of it, I want to set it up as transparent because Im creating custom input that is div with default input inside and div has custom color. I have tried multiple variants, the only one that worked was with white background trough :-webkit but I have light/dark themes and when I change to dark theme the background stays white.

2nd problem is with triggering focus on input. As I said, I have div that has input inside and I trigger .focus() on input when div is clicked but for some reason focus doesnt trigger opening of autofill popup, it is triggered only when I directly click on input

this is my input setup, focus triggering and css setup to remove autofill(I have tried multiple variants for background removal)

```
<input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="on">

this.$refs.input.focus();

input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active {
  transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```